# Set of subsets of bounded $\Omega$ with pairwise symmetric difference bounded from below

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R} ^d$ be bounded and consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.
Given $\epsilon >0$, does there exist a subset $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ with infinitely many elements such that $|A \triangle B| \geq \epsilon$ for all $A\neq B\in \mathcal{A}$?

My intuition tells me that this should not be true, since every two sets in $\mathcal{A}$ "differ" by at least the volume $\epsilon$, but $\Omega$ is bounded.
However, I do not have any idea how to proof this.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to prove your claim, as it appeals to intuition. After correcting the proof, it appeared that $\epsilon$ can be at most $|\Omega|/4$, so I tried constructing such sets by taking subintervals of $(0,1)$ of length $2^{-k}$.

---

Here is an construction for $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $\epsilon=1/4$:
Define
$$
A_1 = (0,1),
$$
$$
A_2 = (0,1/2),
$$
$$
A_3 = (0,1/4) \cup (1/2,3/4),
$$
$$
A_4 = (0,1/8) \cup (1/4,3/8)\cup (1/2,5/8)\cup (3/4,1/8), \dots
$$

---

I believe $\epsilon = |\Omega|/4$ is the best $\epsilon$ possible.

Take such a collection $\mathcal A$ containing at least $k$ sets $A_1 \dots A_k$.

Suppose $x\in \Omega$ is an element of $A_1 \dots A_j$ but not of $A_{j+1} \dots A_k$. Then $x$ belongs to $j \cdot (k-j)$ symmetric differences.
This product is maximal for $j \approx k/2$, so $k^2/4$ is an upper bound.

This implies
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{k} |A_i \Delta A_j| 
= \int_\Omega\sum_{i,j=1}^{k} \chi_{A_i \Delta A_j}dx
\le \frac{k^2}4 |\Omega|.
$$
Due to the lower bound of the symmetric differences, we have
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{k} |A_i \Delta A_j| \ge (k^2 - k) \epsilon,
$$
so that
$$
\frac{k^2}4 |\Omega| \ge (k^2 - k) \epsilon.
$$
If $\mathcal A$ is infinite, then dividing the inequality by $k$ and letting $k\to \infty$ proves $\epsilon \le |\Omega|/4$.

Comment: This is great, thank you. The example for $\Omega = (0,1)$ even works with $\epsilon = 1/2$.

Comment: ? No, $\epsilon$ can at most be $1/4$, that is the second part of the answer.