# Is the Borel sigma algebra compact w.r.t. Fréchet-Nikodym metric?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded, consider the space $X:= \mathcal{B} (\Omega)$ equipped with the metric $d(A,B):=|A \triangle B|$ (where all sets with distance 0 are identified as usual, so we get a metric space $(X,d)$. $d$ is also called Fréchet-Nikodym metric.

It is well-know that X is complete. But is it also compact, i.e. can we show that X is totally bounded?

It was shown here that X contains infinitely many disjoint $\varepsilon$-balls if $\varepsilon$ is small emough:
[Set of subsets of bounded $\Omega$ with pairwise symmetric difference bounded from below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790112/set-of-subsets-of-bounded-omega-with-pairwise-symmetric-difference-bounded-fr)

But this would be no contraction to total boundedness.

Comment: Do you mean $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ ?  You wrote $\in \mathbb R^d$.  I guess you mean Lebesgue measure when you write $|\cdot|$.

Comment: $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$ was a mistake (I corrected it). And yes, $| \cdot |$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

It is not compact.  Take $\Omega = [0,1]$ in $\mathbb R^1$.
Consider the i.i.d. sequence of "Rademacher" sets
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \left[0,\frac12\right]
\\
A_2 &= \left[0,\frac14\right] \cup \left[\frac12,\frac34\right]
\\
A_3 &= \left[0,\frac18\right] \cup \left[\frac14,\frac38\right] \cup
\left[\frac12,\frac58\right] \cup \left[\frac34,\frac78\right]
\end{align}
Then we have $d(A_n,A_m) = \frac12$ for $n \ne m$.  The space is not totally bounded.